# Передать список из JSP в JS

Tags: javascript, java, json, jsp

В файле JSP происходит обработка карты `entry`:

```
Map<String, String> entry = (Map<String, String>)request.getAttribute("currentRep");
```

и далее обработка этой карты.

Я хочу всю логику выполненную на Java убрать и переписать на JS.

Для этого сделал отдельный файл:

```
<script src="${pageContext.request.contextPath}/js/loadListRC.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

Как мне в `loadListRC.js` передать `entry`?
В теории прочел, что нужно сделать контроллер и далее передать данные JSON.

Можете для моего случая показать, как это должно выглядеть?