# Передача данных из jsp в js

Tags: javascript, json, jsp

Как с помощью JSON передать параметр (например map) из страницы jsp в js и затем вернуть рассчитанные данные?

Comment: самое простое на странице указать <script>const json = {test: value};</script> и далее результат расчетов записать в другую переменную, которая сообщит бэкэнду результат

Comment: Похож: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/771597/%d0%9f%d0%b5%d1%80%d0%b5%d0%b4%d0%b0%d1%82%d1%8c-%d1%81%d0%bf%d0%b8%d1%81%d0%be%d0%ba-%d0%b8%d0%b7-jsp-%d0%b2-js дублем не отмечаю, но оставлю тут.